# Help - Saving a DigitaPersona Template file. See sample code

Tags: delphi, fingerprint, biometrics

DELPHI 5 SAMPLE FOR SAVING A DigitaPersona TEMPLATE SERIAL DATA
TO A DBASE4 DBF FILE.

```
procedure TFormEnroll.DPFPEnrollmentControl1Enroll(Sender: TObject;
  lFingerMask: Integer; const pTemplate, pStatus: IDispatch);
var
  MMask : Integer;
  Template : IDispatch;
  MTempStr : OleVariant;

  lByteArray: Variant;
  lArrayPointer: Pointer;
  lStr: AnsiString;
  DPFPTemplate: TDPFPTemplate;
  aRawData : Variant;
begin
  aRawData := pTemplate;
  lStr := aRawData.Serialize;
  MMask := lFingerMask;
  if lStr = null then
    StatusBar.Panels.Items[0].Text := 'The fingerprint TEMPLATE is empty! + Mask=' + IntToStr(MMask)
  else
    StatusBar.Panels.Items[0].Text := 'The fingerprint TEMPLATE has something! + Mask=' + IntToStr(MMask);
  MMsg := lStr;
  MLen := Length(MMsg);
  EditSerialData.Text := MMsg;
  MemoSerialData.Lines.Text := MMsg;
  MemoSerialData2.Lines.Text := MMsg;
  EditLenSerialData.Text := IntToStr(MLen);
  EditFingerMask.Text := IntToStr(DPFPEnrollmentControl1.EnrolledFingersMask);
  //Update database - Take to separate save button
  DMForm.Finger.First;
  if DMForm.Finger.State in [dsEdit, dsInsert] then
    // do nothing
  else
    DMForm.Finger.Edit;
  DMForm.FingerUSERNAME.Value := 'Testing ';
  DMForm.Finger.Post;
  DMForm.Finger.Edit;
  DMForm.FingerUSERNAME.Value := 'Testing ' + IntToStr(DMForm.FingerFINGERID.Value);
  DMForm.FingerFINGERTEMP.Value := MMsg;
  DMForm.FingerEnrolledFingerMask.Value := IntToStr(DPFPEnrollmentControl1.EnrolledFingersMask);
  DMForm.FingerFingerSerialData.Value := MMsg;
  DMForm.Finger.Post;
end;
```

> EXAMPLE STRING OF THE SAVED TEMPLATE = "?b?????????????????????????????????????????????????????õ???????????????????????????????????+???????[??????????????????V????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????9??????????o??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????¦???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????j??????????????????????o????????????????????????????????????????????????????????U·?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????#??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????"

Is this the kind of result we expect?
Is this a workable template?
Can you explain ( aRawData := pTemplate;) the interaction of 'aRawData' which is a variant with 'pTemplate;) ' which is a Dispatch variable.
Am I on the write path?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that's the binary data of the fingerprint template which is used to verify the fingerprint.

You can save it in a blob in a database or a binary file and load it or to bintohex and save it in a text file.

The difference between a template and the rawdata is that the template is the one that is used to verify the finger the next time it is pressed in the reader.  You'll see that if you print out the rawdata that it's a lot bigger.

Looks like you're on the right track, just don't worry about the binary data.